# How to put a GameOject in a Cell of bool Array in c# Unity using a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, boolean, gameobject

Hello dear developers,

as said in the titel i wanted to know if anyone can help me with this Problem. I'm a beginner as in never played with Unity before and
I'm sorry if this is a stupid or obvious question but i really don't see it.

I have to use rejection sampling to avoid collision in Unity and the gamobjects created with a script (prefab) have to be planted in a grid of 20x20 cells, where the Array that builds this grid is a 2D bool Array. Every Gameobject has to be planted in one cell of the grid and the value of the cell has to turn to true if so, so that other Objects can't be build in that cell afterwards. I think I have to compute the size of the cells, but i don't really know how to do this.

I already tried this example below but it still builds gameobjects that collide, so it doesn't really work.

If you have any ideas or helpful advice, that would be great.

```
    public void plant(){
    root = new GameObject();
    root.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
    bool[,] Cell = new bool[20, 20];
    for(int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b < 20; b++){                
            if(Cell[a,b] == false){
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(objPrefab);
                obj.transform.parent = root.transform;

                float x = Random.Range(-50.0f, 50.0f);
                float z = Random.Range(-50.0f, 50.0f);  

                float scale = Random.Range(80.0f, 140.0f);
                float rotation = Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f);


                obj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x,0.0f,z);
                obj.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f,rotation,0.0f), Space.World);
                obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale,scale,scale);
                Cell[a,b] = true;
            }
        }   

    }                   

}
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome? You're setting the bools correctly but you don't want the objects to collide?

Comment: exactly i don't want them to collide, but with that Code they obviously still collide. I have to make sure that every object is build in one celll and if so it's value is set to true. So other objects can't be build in that cell, because it's value is not false.

Comment: You're setting them all to have the same parent and randomizing their position, you should base their position off of their cell index

Comment: That means i have to assign that index to the object, right? how do I do that?